# Mute and delete messages antispam discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
async def on_message(message: object):
    counter = 0
    with open("spam_detect.txt", "r+") as file:
        for lines in file:
            if lines.strip("\n") == str(message.author.id):
                counter += 1

        file.writelines(f"{str(message.author.id)}\n")
        if counter > 5 and not message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            await message.author.send("Ai primit kick pentru spam. Poti intra in `60` secunde.")
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
            await message.guild.ban(message.author, reason="spam")
            await message.channel.send(f"{message.author} a primit kick pentru `spam`.")
            await asyncio.sleep(60)
            await message.guild.unban(message.author)
```

Does anyone know how instead of banning and unbanning someone i can give them the `Muted` role and delete all messages in the past hour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we simply have to get their messages and delete it.

```py
from datetime import datetime
await message.channel.purge(after=datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1), check = lambda x: x.author.id == message.author.id, oldest_first=False) #purges the channel
muted_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Muted')
await message.author.add_roles(muted_role)
await message.channel.send('muted spammer and deleted messages')
```

the `check` parameter makes it delete only the author's messages.

Comment: I get this error. 
```await message.channel.purge(after=datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1), check = lambda x: x.author.id == message.author.id, oldest_first=False) #purges the channel
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'```

(sorry i'm new to python)

Comment: yeah we're not importing the module, see my edit now

Comment: I get a lot of errors..wnen i fix one, another comes. `NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined`
This is my full code: https://pasteio.com/xqEGJSPvhaLv

Comment: what about now?

Comment: Thiss should work: https://pasteio.com/xFKcSW7y2ybf